# List Comprehension tuple over iterator in Python

Tags: python, iterator, list-comprehension

I'm learning about iterators and the groupby function in Python's itertools module. I understand that the following code takes strings of integers and prints tuples (x,y) where x is the number of times y repeats.

```
from itertools import groupby
s = input()
print(*[(len(list(c)), int(k)) for k, c in groupby(s)])
```

What I don't understand is "k, c in groupby(s)" as a part of a list comprehension. It would make sense to me if "groupby(s)" was a list of tuples but it's an iterator.

My question is how does a list comprehension produce a list from two variables over an iterator?

My testing has shown that I can use one variable over an iterator to produce a list. How is that list different?

Comment: You can loop over an iterator of tuples just like a list of tuples. You can loop over an iterator of anything just like a list of anything.

Comment: comprehension constructs **work with iterators**, that's the *whole point of iteration*. This iterator happens to produce something which can be unpacked into two variables, if it didn't this would fail as written. In other words, lists comprehensions *produce lists* from any iterable. Similarly, dictionary comphrensions produce *dictionaries* from any iterable.

Comment: To be clear, I'm not wondering about iterating over an *iterable object* but rather iterating over an iterator. Is it just the case that iterators are 2-tuples? So in my example code "groupby(s)" is iterated 2-tuples and "k,c" iterates over those?

Comment: Iterators are iterable.

Comment: So then how is it being iterated? What is "k,c" doing different from just "k"? Why does "k,c" yield values when the printed tuples have no values in the second position? Where is 'c' getting it's values from?

Comment: "how does a list comprehension produce a list from two variables over an iterator?"

Comment: When you get to a resolution, please remember to up-vote useful things and accept your favourite answer (even if you have to write it yourself), so Stack Overflow can properly archive the question.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't have enough reputation to upvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of groupby(s) is not an iterator but tuples of keys and iterators. Passing two variables, "k,c" assigns k's to keys in groupby(s) and c to iterators in groupby(s).

There is ambiguity because

```
for k,c in groupby(s)
```

is the same as

```
for (k,c) in groupby(s)
```

where k and c are assigned to values within the tuples, and

```
for k in groupby(s)
```

assigns k to the tuples themselves.

Also, in the example code list(c) creates list with the iterator c.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that **groupby(s)** will return a series of pairs (tuples of length 2).  You can bind each of these to a pair of variables.

As a general concept, this works just as if **groupby(s)** resolved to a list of the same pairs.  The actual list comprehension can use *any* iterable at the right end; it's not restricted to a static sequence (list, tuple, string).

**EXAMPLE**

Let's look at a better example.  **groupby** gathers adjacent elements with the same value.  It does this with an iterator for each contiguous group of values.  The sample string below has contiguous strings of B, C, D, and Z, and two separate strings of a single A.  **groupby** will instantiate an iterator for each starting location; when invoked, the iterator will return a sequence of the consecutive letters, shown in the output.

```
from itertools import groupby
s = "BBCCCDDDDAZZA"
for k, c in groupby(s):
    print k, list(c)
```

Output:

```
B ['B', 'B']
C ['C', 'C', 'C']
D ['D', 'D', 'D', 'D']
A ['A']
Z ['Z', 'Z']
A ['A']
```

As you've noted, if we print merely the iterator **c**, all we get is the object handle.  To obtain the letters, we need to invoke the iterator.

In the code you posted,

```
for k, c in groupby(s)
```

receives the series of (letter, iterator) pairs from **groupby**.  The **list** function is what invokes the iterator, fetching the list of letters.

Does that clarify things at all?

Comment: This **print** will print the object: a generator / iterator handle.  If you want to see the result list, try **print [_ for _ in groupby(s)]**

Comment: I'm still confused. For s = 123
print(*groupby(s))
yields
('1', ) ('2', ) ('3', )
And these have no values in the second position of the pairs. Therefore it doesn't seem like "groupby(s)" is being treated as an iterated list of pairs.

Comment: print(*(_ for _  in groupby(s)))  yields the same: ('1', ) ('2', ) ('3', )

It's still not clear to me how "k, c" iterates over this.

Comment: When I use that line, I get each element followed by a *grouper object* for that element.  I used **s="123"** (string rather than int, which is not iterable).  Does the [groupby doc](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) help?

Comment: Right, string '123'. Sorry, I typod that.   print((_ for _ in groupby(s))) yields just a memory location so I did print(*(_ for _ in groupby(s))) which yielded what I wrote earlier. It's not clear what it yielded for you. There are more than a couple problems with my understanding but I think we can point to it by asking, "what is happening with 'k,c'"?

Comment: the groupby doc isn't very helpful. It states that the output is an iterator. It doesn't really help with how to manipulate that iterator, specifically to make a list over it via a list comprehension. I think my most relevant gap in knowledge is about iterators and list comprehensions, specifically what it means to make a list using two variables over an iterator.

Comment: "for k, c in groupby(s)
receives the series of (letter, iterator) pairs from groupby. The list function is what invokes the iterator, fetching the list of letters.

Does that clarify things at all?"

It really helped me to realize that "for k, c in groupby(s)" is the same as "for k in groupby(s) and for c in groupby(s)". I noticed that "list" in "list(c)" invokes the iterator to get the values. The only thing that is still not clear to me is where int(k) is getting its values. Actually, I'm doing some tests now and I'm doubting what little understanding I have.

Comment: "print(*[(int(c), int(k)) for k, c in groupby(s)])" Throws the following error: "TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'itertools._grouper'"

Why would the first value of the touple throw an error as an int but not the second?

Comment: Well, that's because you changed something.  **int** converts a string to its integer equivalent.  You fed it an iterator.

Comment: **int(k)** gets its values from the series of **k** values in the **for** clause.  This is the first element of each tuple returned from **groupby**.  My example changed from numbers to letters to illustrate the principles; that string will not work in the original code.

Comment: In your letter example can you swap c and k? does their order matter?

Comment: I swapped them only in the output order.  My usage is still consistent with the **groupby** order.

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding what the return of "groupby()" is. Is it tuples in the form (values, iterator)?

Comment: I mean is "for k, c in groupby(s):" the same as "for c, k in groupby(s):"?

Comment: Yes, it returns those tuples.  The variable order *within that clause* is immaterial: they are just variables.  What matters is how you use them after you do that assignment.  In the "c, k" example, c becomes the value and k becomes the iterator.

Comment: "In the 'c, k' example, c becomes the value and k becomes the iterator..." whereas with 'k,c' k is the value and c becomes the iterator, right? It seems like the output of groupby() is 2-tuples in the form (x,y) where x is a value and y is an iterator. Is that right? Furthermore, it would seem that "for x,y in z" means "for 2-touples (x,y) in z, which has 2-touples."

Comment: Right.  **groupby** returns those tuples, and that's how multiple assignment works.